# How To Call Methods In Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variables, object, methods, console

I'm having an issue calling methods in a fairly simple script.

For some reason, when I run the program, all I get in the console is return 0.

What can I do to fix it? Here's my script:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface person:NSObject {
    int weight;
    int height;
    int age;
}

- (void)printtoscreen;
- (void)setweight:(int)w;
- (void)setheight:(int)h;
- (void)setage:(int)a;

@end

@implementation person

-(void) printtoscreen {   
    NSLog(@"I am %i years old, I weigh %i pounds, and I am %i feet tall", age, weight, height);
}

- (void)setweight:(int)w {
    w=weight; 
}

- (void)setheight:(int)h {
    h=height;
}

- (void)setage:(int)a {
    a=age; 
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   @autoreleasepool {
       person *bob;
       [bob setweight:150];
       [bob setheight:5];
       [bob setage:25];
       [bob printtoscreen];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem is that we never actually create an object, so all of our messages are sent to `nil`.

The first and most immediate fix you must make is actually instantiating the object:

```
person *bob = [[person alloc] init];
```

This must be done before any of our methods are actually called on an object.

Now, we must fix the methods that *Jens* mentioned.  Our assignments our backwards.  The argument should be the right-value and the instance variable should be the left-value:

```
- (void)setweight:(int)w {
    weight = w;
}
```

With these two fixes, all should work.

Comment: There are also some style and OOP issues in the code in the question.  I'm assuming this asker is in the first week or so of a programming class, so I'm opting not to mention them as it might confuse and distract from the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter are totaly wrong:

```
-(void) setweight: (int) w {
w=weight;
}
```

should be:

```
-(void) setweight: (int) w {
weight = w; 
}
```

And so on for the other setter

Comment: This is only part of the problem.

Comment: @nhgrif What would you say with this comment? Please explain your downvote.

Comment: See my answer.  If this were the only problem, we'd see this on the log: `I am 0 years old, I weigh 0 pounds, and I am 0 feet tall` (or perhaps some random numbers... I can't remember... but **something** would print)